# Why isn't font-squirrel @font-face generator working in IE8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, font-face, eot

BACKGROUND:
I've directly downloaded a package from font-squirrel.  I've done zero manipulation to this @font-face package. Additionally, the package has worked on every modern browser.

CODE:
I've uploaded the code to my server: http://designobvio.us/font/accent-demo.html

QUESTION:
Does anyone know why IE8 or lower isnt rendering this @font-face?

RESEARCH:
I know EOT is in the package.  I've read so many articles.  Most of them were understanding how @font-face works.  I feel as if I understand more about @font-face then I need too; nevertheless, none of the reads are solving the problem.  The closest answer is that's possible is that, IEtester isnt rendering correctly.  [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173095/fontface-in-ie7-ietester-not-working-properly)

NOTES:
I really don't think it is IE-tester that is messing this up (for I've tested various other sites that I know have @font-face [example](http://www.pixeltheory.cc/)).  Nevertheless, if anyone can vm test or has xp to test this that would be great.

Comment: We solved an issue with EOT files in the Generator today that was causing some fonts to not load in IE. Try it again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that Font-squirrel is going through some maintenance right now.  I would have to assume that this is the reason why their generator isnt properly converting files.  I solved this problem by useing another converter for fonts.  [found here!](http://fontface.codeandmore.com/)  I'm not sure as to why but the fonts also became 20kbs smaller using this generator vs font-squirrel.  If anyone has any ideas why this generator reduces file sizes that would be great i'll upvote ya.  I hope this stops some headaches.